# Logical OR on F-expressions in Django ORM

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite, orm

I have a query like

```
User.objects.annotate(
    x=Value(False, output_field=BooleanField()),
    y=Value(True, output_field=BooleanField())
).annotate(
    z=F('x').bitor(F('y'))  # HOW TO DO THIS?
).values('z')
```

which works with SQLite but not with PostgreSQL. The error is

```
LINE 1: SELECT (false | true) AS "z" FROM "auth_user"  LIMIT 21
                      ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How should I implement the logical OR on annotated fields that works consistently?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Django doesn't provide logical operators for `Expression` objects on its own, but deeper into the framework both `Value` and `F` inherit from the `Combinable` class. This class actually provides us with operators we can use, unfortunately not boolean ones.

If both of our values are resolvable to an expression (`Values` are) we can pass the operator to the database ourselves. To do this we will do exactly what `Combinable` does - initialize the `CombinedExpression` object:

```
User.objects.annotate(
        x=Value(False, output_field=BooleanField()),
        y=Value(True, output_field=BooleanField())
    ).annotate(
        z=CombinedExpression(lhs=F('x'), rhs=F('y'), connector="OR")
    ).values('z')
```

This solution might not be compliant with all databases but it works with PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

Cast it to interger type when using bitwise operator

```py
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

User.objects.annotate(
    x=Value(False, output_field=BooleanField()),
    y=Value(True, output_field=BooleanField())
).annotate(
    z=Cast(Cast(F('x'), IntergerField()).bitor(Cast(F('y'), IntergerField())), BooleanField())
).values('z')
```